# How to call a WCF Windows service as a raw TCP request

Tags: .net, wcf, service, tcp

I've got a problem. I've been googling and I can't figure out what to do so any help would very much be appreciated. Basically I have a Windows Wcf service on the App Tier (which doesnt and wont ever have IIS installed on it). As part of security testing, I need to send a manually created TCP request to a Wcf service. The Windows service ONLY has a NetTcpBinding and nothing else. My solution needs to create a TCP request as part of a SOAP message, send it to the Wcf service and get the response back. I have no problems when using the Wcf Test Client so I know the Wcf service works. Could somebody please help??

From what I gather after reading around the msdn website etc.... I need to use sockets and create a SOAP request, but all the examples focus around a wsHttpBinding when mine has to be a netTcpBinding.

Thanks

Comment: You have a WCF service with a TCP endpoint that you want to call from another tier? When you say "manually created TCP request" what do you mean exactly? You just want to invoke an operation on the TCP endpoint?

Comment: I'll be calling the WCF service from a different machine (probably a different App Tier), but it'll be on the same network. 

Yes. So I basically just want to code a request that would invoke a method on the Wcf service. For example, if it was over a HTTPBinding, I could code up a HttpWebRequest (or something along those lines). I basically need to do the same thing but for a Tcp connection and without using any proxy references.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link:
[Build raw soap messages](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/3612be9c-c501-442b-a174-0c069639eac1/)

You can build un-typed messages and send the over the wire.

Cheers,

Gilad

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, I think it's as simple as using a [ChannelFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms576132.aspx) with a [NetTcpBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.nettcpbinding.aspx). So something like this:

```
NetTcpBinding binding = new NetTcpBinding();
EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddress("Your URI");

ChannelFactory<IContract> factory = new ChannelFactory<IContract>(binding, address);
IContract channel = factory.CreateChannel();

channel.YourOperation();

((ICommunicationObject)channel).Close();
```